# prefix cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, discord

I'm trying to code a discord bot in Java and I'm following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59OllBJlU1c

However I now have two errors stating that token and prefix cannot be resolved or are not fields, even though I'm following the video almost to the letter

```
public class App extends ListenerAdapter
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        JDA jda = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT).setToken(Ref.token).buildBlocking();
        jda.addEventListener(new App());
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent evt) {

        //Objects
        User objUser =  evt.getAuthor();
        MessageChannel objMsgCh = evt.getChannel();
        Message objMsg = evt.getMessage();


        //Commands
        if(objMsg.getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase(Ref.prefix+"rtd"));
    }
}
```

Along with the Ref class:

```
public class Ref {
    public static final String token = "";
    public static final String prefix = ">";

}
```

Any help is appreciated, sorry if I formatted something wrong, this is my first time asking a question

Comment: Is `Ref` in the same package as `App`?  If not, have you imported it?

Comment: Yes they are both in the same package

Comment: Are the `App` and `Ref` classes in separate files or they are in only one file?

Comment: I mean... they are in separate files like `App.java` and `Ref.java`?

Comment: If I am not wrong You need to use `import Ref` I dont know Java so I dont know :p